# Possible to determine if "callable" is function or class method?

Tags: php

In PHP a [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) is either a normal function or a class method.

I want to check if a callable is (1) a simple function or (2) a class method. If it is a class method, how can I find the class-name of the callable?

```
// The function:
function callable_type( $var ) {
    if ( ! is_callable( $var ) ) {
        return 'no callable';
    }

    $type_info = ... how to check the exact type?

    return $type_info;
}

// Test:
function fn_a() {}
class Cls {
    function fn_b() {}
    static function fn_c() {}
}

$callable1 = 'fn_a';
$callable2 = array( new Cls, 'fn_b' );
$callable3 = 'Cls::fn_c';

echo callable_type( $callable1 ); // echo 'function'
echo callable_type( $callable2 ); // echo 'method of Cls'
echo callable_type( $callable3 ); // echo 'method of Cls'
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're trying to achieve... if there's a `new Thing` or `Thing::method()` then it's an object... and if you've got `$thing->method()` you know it's an object ... and if you've just got `$thing` (and it's an object) then it wouldn't be callable anyway - you could check that it's an object with `is_object()` I guess.

Comment: Check if it's an array, inspect its first element…? If it's a string, check with something like the regex `/^(\w+)::\w+/`?

Comment: Why do you need this? It sounds like you are trying to fix a design issue in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_callable` returns the callable name as string as it's third parameter (It's a reference), we can use that to parse the name. If it contains a `::`, it's a class method, otherwise a free function:

```
function callable_type( $var ) {
    if ( ! is_callable( $var, false, $name) ) {
        return 'no callable';
    }

    if($name === "Closure::__invoke")
        return "Closure";

    $name = explode("::", $name);

    if(count($name) === 1)
        return "Free function '" . $name[0] . "'";

    return "Class method '" . $name[1] . "' of class '" . $name[0] . "'";
}
```

Used with the following input:

```
function fn_a() {}
class Cls {
    function fn_b() {}
    static function fn_c() {}
}

$callable1 = 'fn_a';
$callable2 = array( new Cls, 'fn_b' );
$callable3 = 'Cls::fn_c';

echo callable_type( $callable1 ) . "\n";
echo callable_type( $callable2 ) . "\n";
echo callable_type( $callable3 ) . "\n";
echo callable_type(function() {}) . "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
Free function 'fn_a'
Class method 'fn_b' of class 'Cls'
Class method 'fn_c' of class 'Cls'
Closure
```

Comment: Perfect! Did not know about the third param of `is_callable()`. Thanks :)